# Workflow Foundation replication across databases

Tags: .net, security, workflow-foundation, dynamics-crm, database-replication

I'm new to Workflow Foundation and have a question related to replication in a secure model.

**Background**

Basically we have two systems: Internal and public. The internal system needs high security and hence will not be accessible from the outside. The public system is web based and can be used by anyone on the internet.

These servers have the usual layer of protection; SQL not directly accessible from internet, firewalls in front, etc. But there is always a chance of some future IIS exploit giving remote access to modify ASPX so hacker can gain access to SQL and modify content. So I use this assumption as a basis.

The workflow for these systems will be the same, but obviously we can't give public access to the internal DB and I have concerns about giving a public server authority for the workflow happening internally.

**Questions**

So I'm considering a model where internal workflow is replicated to external DB on every change / every night. Any my questions revolves around this problem.

1. Is it possible to replicate changes in the workflow from DB to DB?
2. Will it have impact on workflows/tasks already in progress?
3. Any comments / views on how to solve this problem?
4. And a bonus question: Can one of the WF (the internal) be in Dynamics CRM's WF engine?

Note that the actual tasks happening internally and public is not related. Only the workflow itself is.

**Edit:** Latest WF version prefered unless it is possible to sync with Dynamics CRM and CRM puts some limit on it.

Comment: WF 3/3.5 or WF 4? (They are very different.)

Comment: Undetermined, but I guess 4.0 is preferred.

Comment: So a workflow may be started on the public server but continued by an operation on the internal server or vice-versa?  If that is the case don't you run the risk of secure internal data being inadvertantly revealed in the public site?  If the public site can run workflows that affect the internal site (even by replicated data) then that represents a security hole.  Am I understanding correctly?